# Pushing Assets to the Browser - Your Own Theme Module

Tags: apostrophe-cms

For some beginners including myself , still figuring out on how to make our own theme module. But this is how I found a solution myself. Please Note : I don't know if this effects the performance issue on ApostropheCMS , but I'll leave this as a solution for all of us. Let's Begin ! (See Answer Below) :

Comment: Hi Amin, thanks for posting this, I'm sure it will be helpful for others. That being said, you shouldn't link your assets in your nunjucks templates, as this is already being taken care of by pushAssets. 

If things weren't showing up, perhaps you didn't restart your node server?

Comment: Hi @Tortilaman , thank you for clarifying that up. I tested your solution that I don't have to include in my nunjucks templates. However, when I did testing a simple body{background-color : #000} and restart my node server. It does not output my body color of the page ! When I include them in nunjucks template , it works !

Comment: You should not post the answer to a question in the question body itself. If you want to answer your own question, do it as a separate answer so it's clear what the question is and what the answer to that question is. Also, this way people see that the question has an accepted answer when they're browsing.

Comment: Thank you @MihaiChelaru . I'm a beginner to this Stack Overflow. Will amend this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER FOR ALL APOSTROPHE DEVELOPERS BEGINNERS**

We followed tutorial from [Pushing Assets to the Browser](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/pushing-assets.html#assets-in-a-theme-module) , but there is a missing plot somehow on why the assets is still cannot be found. Let's say we have created our own theme module based on that tutorial here. I put mine for example :

```js
my-theme
  - public/
     - css/
         - bootstrap/
             - bootstrap.min.css
         - font-awesome/
             - font-awesome.min.css
     - js/
         - bootstrap/
             - bootstrap.min.js
   - index.js
```

Then , you must put this in **app.js** to load the module :

```js
  modules: {
      // in app.js
      // other config above
      // include my own-theme-module
      'my-theme' : {},
```

Then , in our **my-theme/index.js** , these are my pushAsset method :

```js
module.exports = {
    construct : function(self,options){
        // Every asset you have in public folder
        self.pushAsset('script', 'bootstrap/bootstrap.min');
        self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'bootstrap/bootstrap.min');
        self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'custom');
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : You don't have to include a link or script tag in your nunjucks template because it will make your performance issue on ApostropheCMS where minification process may not take if you put a link/script tags in nunjucks template. Let the Apostrophe made it for you , your job is only pushAsset ;)

Now, what if you have TOO MANY ASSETS , and you're too lazy to write the code everytime you upload a new asset , I have a shortcut using lodash , simple ! . In **my-theme/index.js** :

```js
var _ = require('lodash');
module.exports = {
    stylesheets : [
        {   // Make sure your directory after css folder is correct for specific search
            name : 'bootstrap/bootstrap.min'
        },
        {
            name : 'custom'
        },
        {
            name : 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min'
        }
    ],
    scripts : [
        {
            name : 'bootstrap/bootstrap.min'
        }
    ],
    construct : function(self,options){
        // Every asset you have in public folder
        _.each(options.stylesheets || [] , function(item){
            self.pushAsset('stylesheet', item.name);
        });
        _.each(options.scripts || [] , function(item){
            self.pushAsset('script' , item.name)
        });
    }
}
```

---

What if I want to do `<img>` tag with my custom asset PNG for example ? Do I need to pushAsset too ?

> Answer : NO , you don't have to push asset because its only works on Stylesheets and Scripts . Once you load the module in app.js , the apostrophe automatically upload the asset to the url to `/modules/module-name/path-to-asset/` . For Example : `<img src="/modules/my-theme/img/icon.png">` Simple !

---

**YOU'RE DONE !**

ANOTHER NOTE : If you need to call your asset ONLY via CSS for background-image that using **url()** or font-face, you need to call by using your own module name : `/modules/your-module-name/path-to-your-asset/` . EASY ! !

**AND REMEMBER , DON'T PUT *LINK* and *SCRIPT* tag to link an asset that you pushed. Apostrophe HAS MADE IT FOR YOU FOR POWERFUL PERFORMANCE ! Again , your job is to push the Asset ONLY.**

Comment: Hi Amin, it does not make sense to both write your own link/script tags and push the assets. In fact writing your own link and script tags duplicates the function of pushing the assets completely, so you may as well not push them if you're going to do that. You're also losing the minification benefits in production and making extra HTTP requests.

I will add an example of a custom "theme module" to the apostrophe-examples project to clarify how this can successfully be done.

Comment: Got it @TomBoutell . Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary or advisable to write your own `link` and `script` tags because this prevents Apostrophe from minifying your assets in production, and from compiling your LESS files as a single unit with the benefits of shared mixins, etc.

However, the [apostrophe-samples project](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-samples) now contains a working example of a "theme" module. I have moved the assets sometimes found at project level in `apostrophe-assets` to the `theme` module to demonstrate how this can correctly be done.

The key elements are:

- Don't forget to enable your `theme` module in app.js.
- In `lib/modules/theme/index.js`, push the assets you need in `construct`, or a method called from `construct`.
- Put those assets in the `public/css` and `public/js` subdirectories of your `theme` module.

See the [apostrophe-samples project](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-samples) for the exact working code.

To learn about Apostrophe in production and how to minify assets there with no additional code, see [Apostrophe in production](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/deployment.html).

Thanks for the nudge to bring this use case into the samples project.